# Sequelize, Typescript - typescript make an error to model's getter method

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Let's say, I have two models `User` and `Post`, and they are associated as one to many relationship:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    ...
});

const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
    ...
});

User.hasMany(Post);
```

Then if I get some posts from a user using `getPosts` method,

```
const user = await User.findOne({...});
const posts = await user.getPosts();
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

Typescript makes an error:

> error TS2339: Property 'getPosts' does not exist on type '{}'.

What should I do for it? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, the TypeScript typings for Sequelize are incomplete.  You can specify the attributes of your objects when you call `sequelize.define` as shown [here](https://michalzalecki.com/using-sequelize-with-typescript/), but this won't declare a `getPosts` method AFAIK.  The [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript) package appears to offer [an alternative way to get related objects](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#type-safe-usage-of-auto-generated-functions), though I haven't tried any of this myself.

Comment: I didn't want to use `sequelize-typescript` :( but I should use it unavoidably.